# Finding the lub and glb of set.

Tags: real-analysis

the question is ,
  find lub and glb of set $S = \{ m + \frac{1}{n} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
my approach : clearly glb of set is $1$ because if put $m = 1$ and when $n$ tends to infinity then $m + \frac{1}{n} = 1$, but what is the lub of $S$? note that here $m, n$ are not fixed numbers.

Comment: first you need to show the set is bounded.  Consider a subset so that  $n=1$, can you find a lub of this subset?

Comment: So, what if $m$ tends to infinity?

Comment: @Andres you are comparing $m+\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{m+1}{n}$.  Without more information, you should assume it is the former, not the latter as there are no parenthesis.

Comment: I see, you are probably correct.

Comment: if we fixed the numbers. as you said, when n = 1 then glb = 2 and lub  does not exists. I think

Comment: The glb is $1$ of the set $\{m+\frac{1}{n}~|~m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  The glb is $0$ of the set $\{\frac{m+1}{n}~|~m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  As you see, there is no finite upper bound.  If you prefer to say the upper bound is $+\infty$ or if you prefer to say it doesn't exist is personal preference.  Both are used.

Comment: @JMoravitz are you sure about your second sentence? But yes, the point is that $m$ is unbounded, and so the set itself has no upper bound

Comment: @Andres Good catch, indeed, I was going off of what was said earlier instead of thinking for myself.  It is zero.

Comment: thanks for helping. I am quite sure that, glb of given set exists and is 1∈ S and lub does not exists and lub ∉ S

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to summarize the conversation and respond to your very last comment.

Let $S= \{m+\frac{1}{n} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

There is no least upper bound. Consider the subset:  $A \subseteq S$ such that $A= \{m+\frac{1}{n} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N}, n=1\}$. Then If $r \in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound, by the archimedean property, there exists some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $m-1 \leq r < m$, a contradiction.

You have already found the $\textrm{glb}$, yet you state that $1= \textrm{glb} S \in S$.

Assume that $1 \in S$. Clearly if $m>1$, then $m+\frac{1}{n}>1$. So we can safely assume that if $1 \in S$, $m=1$. But then there must exist some $n$ so that $1+\frac{1}{n}=1$, or equivalently so that $\frac{1}{n}=0$. There is very clearly no such $n \in \mathbb{N}$, as you can verify. the greatest lower bound is *not* in $S$.